# Libgdx Animation using images from TextureAtlas gets incorrectly rotated

Tags: animation, libgdx, texture-atlas

In my `TextureAtlas` the `Sprite`'s for my `Animation` are rotated 90 degrees.

When I draw my `Animation` it's still rotaed by 90 degrees. How can I fix that?

My code looks like that:

```
    TextureAtlas spritesheet = new TextureAtlas(Gdx.files.internal("images/spritesheet/spritesheet.atlas"));
    Array<AtlasRegion> CLOUD_ANIMATION_REGIONS = spritesheet.findRegions("cloud_animation");
    Animation animation = new Animation(0.1f,ImageProvider.CLOUD_ANIMATION_REGIONS);
```

In the render method:

```
    batch.draw(animation.getKeyFrame(elapsedTime, true), x, y);
```

The animation works perfectly fien but it's rotated by 90 degree like in the spritesheet.

I realize that if I have a `Sprite` I can call `Sprite.draw(batch)` and it will fix the rotation but I don't seem to be able to use that mechanism for `Animation`'s?

**EDIT:**

Like Alexander said, this will do the trick:

```
batch.draw(textureRegion, x, y, 0, 0,textureRegion.getRegionWidth(), textureRegion.getRegionHeight(), 1, 1, 90);
```

Comment: I suppose a few of your sprites are rotated in the spritesheet, not all of them. Is it correct?

Comment: All of the spites needed for the animation are rotated, some other sprites are not rotated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, here is untested code:

```
TextureRegion textureRegion = animation.getKeyFrame(elapsedTime, true);
if (textureRegion instanceof TextureAtlas.AtlasRegion && ((TextureAtlas.AtlasRegion) textureRegion).rotate)
{
    batch.draw(textureRegion, x, y, 0, 0, textureRegion.getRegionWidth(), textureRegion.getRegionHeight(), 1, 1, 90, true);
}
else
{
    batch.draw(textureRegion, x, y);
}
```

What I'm doing here: I check if atlas packer marked the region as rotated and then draw it rotated 90 angle clockwise to compensate original 90 angle counter-clockwise rotation. See [AtlasRegion's javadoc](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/TextureAtlas.AtlasRegion.html) and special version of [draw method](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/SpriteBatch.html#draw-com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureRegion-float-float-float-float-float-float-float-float-float-boolean-) that can rotate TextureRegion.

EDITED: fix arguments based on Markus comment

Comment: I assume the correct usage is: batch.draw(textureRegion, x, y, 0, 0,textureRegion.getRegionWidth(), textureRegion.getRegionHeight(), 0, 0, 90);   , but still the image doesn't rotate, no matter what rotation I enter.

Comment: Do you use built-in [TexturePacker](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Texture-packer)?

Comment: Can you bring your .atlas file? May be export doesn't flag region as rotated.

Comment: Oh thank you but I could fix it with your help. The final problem was that I had used 0 for scale x and scale y which made it invisible. Using 1 for the scalings did the job. Thanks again!

Comment: Oh, I see. Not at all.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow you should be using AtlasSprite I think. That carries out the unrotate in its constructor. You dont want to be rotating every frame - thats some overhead. Also the AtlasSprite should take care of trimmed regions in the atlas : something thats very important to maximise a single atlas texture. Alas it doesnt seem very easy to use as it seems one needs a seperate sprite for each frame which seems massive overhead.

Comment: If I remember I finally went with avoiding rotated textures in the atlas at all. I didn't know about AtlasSprite. I'll give it a look. Thanks for your comment.